# Android Location capture in every 15 minutes

Tags: java, android, location, autostart

I am developing an android app using Java with minimum api level is 16 and target level is 29. Application worked perfectly with android emulator(android 10). But when i checked the same with my vivo phone, foreground service is killed by os. After research i noted that auto start option is disable in phone. I got a code to redirect the user to enable auto start option. But it will call every time when the use call the activity. I have mentioned the same code. Kindly help me regarding the following questions

1. How to check auto start is enabled in phone pragmatically?
2. Is there any other option available to overcome the app killing issue?

   enter code here

private void addAutoStartup() {

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
        } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }
        else if ("Huaewi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if  (list.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exc" , String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the best way to make sure your service will work is to trigger app from outside. I use FCM. The notification fires FirebaseMessagingService in which you can run your tasks. FirebaseMessagingSerwice will not be killed by the system.

Comment: I had also faced same issue few months back and I searched and worked a lot with location on my Vivo phone but I didn't find a suitable way. 
There is no any way to check either auto start is enabled or not. And you can't keep getting location after the app killed by OS above Android N.
As, @MarkWalczak said about FCM, it also doesn't work in the app after getting killed by OS.
But here, you can show an alert dialog about auto start to the user and ask him to goto settings and enable the app and then for the next time you can disable dialog showing by saving a flag value in the shared pref.

Comment: for question 1 - Its just a guess but you can check `PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(String packageName)`. As for question 2 - sadly there is no way. Each manufacturer provides own way of restricting apps and there may be no API for you to check if its whitelisted. If this is a production application - I doubt you can nice way disabling restrictions. If this application is just for you - check [this site](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) and learn how to keep your app alive

Comment: @MarkWalczak Thanks for your comment. I will try with FCM.

Comment: @IrfanAkram Thanks. What will do if the user not enable auto start in the first time?. The flag will set to false.Can you show give some suggestion?

Comment: @artman Thanks. I already tried the library you have given. Unfortunately the same also not working.

Comment: The only thing you can request a user to enable auto start by showing a request message, there is no way around :D

Comment: Auto start is automatically enabled on Whatsapp,truecaller and facebook. Can you explain that. Also any ADB commands are available?

Comment: @Irfan Akram FirebaseMessagingService will always fire. If you send data type massage the device's system trey will handle it.

Comment: @RobinBaby - these few apps are whitelisted by default from the manufacturers.